Fastest way to track dominant eigenvector of recursively updated correlation matrix
Consider a real vector time series: $\mathbf{x}_k\in{\mathbb{R}}^{N \times 1}$ where $k$ is the sample index.  An associated correlation matrix is updated recursively as:
$${\bf R}_k = \alpha {\bf R}_{k-1} + (1-\alpha){\bf x}_k {\bf x}_k^T\qquad 0<\alpha<1$$
where $(\cdot)^T$ denotes transpose.  The eigen-decomposition of ${\bf R}_k$ may be written as:
$${\bf R}_k = {\bf E}_k {\bf \Lambda}_k {\bf E}_k^T$$
where the columns of ${\bf E}_k\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ are the eigen-vectors of ${\bf R}_k$: ${\bf e}_{0_k}, {\bf e}_{1_k}, \cdots {\bf e}_{N_k}$,  and the diagonal elements of ${\bf \Lambda}_k\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ are the ordered eigenvalues: $\lambda_{0_k} \ge \lambda_{1_k} \cdots \ge \lambda_{N_k}$.
There are recursive methods for tracking $ {\bf E}_k $ and ${\bf \Lambda}_k$ e.g., here.
But, in my application, I only need to track ${\bf e}_{0_k}$, the eigen-vector associated with the dominant eigenvalue.  Also, the dimension of the data is small, $N=3$.  I'm wondering whether there are any algorithms that are explicitly designed for my scenario that would be more efficient than updating of the full eigen-structure of the covariance matrix.
Some variant of the power iteration method comes to mind, but was wondering if there was anything better.
Also found this from 1995 (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/365290) which, for a different updating rule for the correlation matrix, results in the so-called "Oja learning rule."  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oja%27s_rule).  Looks simple--not sure about performance.

The dominant eigenvector may change discontinuously, so there's no differential update rule that singles it out.
